# WSO2 EI , foreach using Payload

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Here is my constructed response on the console 
[image: 2ei]

But below is returned as response :

```
{
    "value": {
        "result": {
            "cif": "00156320",
            "accNo": 5002416303,
            "ccy": "MNT"
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem ?

It shows as json array, But it returns just one random element?

Comment: Could you please add your input message to foreach mediator and the implementation of your sequence?

Comment: i solved it using call blocking="true" 
IDK why

Comment: Share your proxy, sequence to see why.

Comment: Can you share your proxy or API, So we can check what is wrong here.